# \Q is ignored it seams

Tags: regex, perl

Can someone tell me why my script below search/replace when I am using `\Q$btype` when it works when I hard code with `center` instead?

The script is suppose to insert `$$` after `\end{center}`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $line = '\end{tabular}
\end{center}
end:text
';

my $btype = "center";
$line =~ s/\\end\{\Q$btype\}/\\end\{\Q$btype\}\$\$/g;
print "$line\n";
```

Comment: @syck: No, `\Q` isn't an anchor. It is a sequence that controls how double-quoted strings are expanded, and has nothing to do with regexes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to stop the escaping:

```
$line =~ s/\\end\{\Q$btype\E\}/\\end\{$btype\}\$\$/g;
#                  here __^^
```

it could be reduce to:

```
$line =~ s/\\end\{\Q$btype\E\}\K/\$\$/g;    # 5.10+
```

or

```
$line =~ s/(\\end\{\Q$btype\E\})/$1\$\$/g;
```

or

```
$line =~ s/\\end\{\Q$btype\E\}/$&\$\$/g;
```

From  ThisSuitIsBlackNot's comment:
Don't use it with perl before v5.20 because of [performance issue](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues).

or

```
$line =~ s/(?<=\\end\{\Q$btype\E\})/\$\$/g;
```

Comment: Since `\Q` is also present in the replacement, I assumed that it should not be used as an anchor.

Comment: @syck:I've removed `\Q` from replacement part.

Comment: @syck it looks more like the OP doesn't fully understand how the substitution works as she also escapes curlies in the right part of the `s///`. Thus it stands to reason that she believes she needs to escape everything.

Comment: This is when tech ends and psychology starts. =)

Comment: `$&` has [performance issues](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Performance-issues) on all versions of Perl prior to 5.20.0, so I wouldn't bother mentioning it when you can just as easily use a capturing group.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot:You're right, I've edited accordingly.

Comment: I don't know why you added #3 and #4. There's never a reason to use them over #1 and #2. (#3 is just as slow #2 plus it slows down every other match without captures in the entire program, and #4 is slower than the others since it has to starts a subregex match at every position).

Comment: There's no reason to show methods one should never use except to tell others never to use them, but you didn't do that.

Comment: If special regex characters need to be ignored for the first occurrence of the `$btype` variable with `\Q...\E`, why you don't use it for the second occurrence? `$line =~ s/\\end\{\Q$btype\E\}/\\end\{\Q$btype\E\}\$\$/g;` or `$line =~ s/\\end{\Q$btype\E}/\\end{\Q$btype}$$/g;`. As an aside, you only need to escape curly brackets if you use perl6 *( and if it isn't ambiguous with perl5 off course)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Because the second occurrence is on the RHS of the substitution. The RHS isn't a regex, so you end up with a bunch of superfluous backslashes in your replacement if you use `\Q`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Also, newer versions of perl5 warn about unescaped curlies and it will become a syntax error in a future version (maybe even 5.26.0 next year).

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: oops, you are right, I didn't see it!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: *" it will become a syntax error in a future version (maybe even 5.26.0 next year)"*, what a stupid upgrade! (Many things are interesting in perl6, but also many things seem to be a regression, in particular if you consider the conciseness of perl5 regex. The false idea that more verbose is always more readable).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte [Here's](https://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2012/11/msg195425.html) some of the reasoning.